# i need javascript for count-up timer continue after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a count-up timer script:

```
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}
```

I need to continue counting after refresh the page.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if it solves your problem!

Answer (score 2):

First, I have to point out that a setInterval of 1000ms rarely perform a real 1000ms delay, this is not reliable when you are using a timer.

Ref: https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9

My suggestion (that also make persisting the timer easier) is to 
 - save the start date for the timer in UTC in localStorage
 - calulate elapsed time by the delta of current time - local storage time
 - Express the delta in hours, minutes and seconds.

When bootstrapping the timer, read from localStorage the starting timer and then desume what to display.

Comment: Outstanding answer!

Comment: Thx NemoStein, I've learned to manage timers in this way when I had to deal with multiplayers data prediction/reconciliation algorithms

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current count in the `localStorage`.

```
var totalSeconds = localStorage.getItem("totalSeconds") || 0;

function setTime() {
  // Your code ...
  localStorage.setItem("totalSeconds", totalSeconds);
}
```

EDIT: Mosè's answer is a way better and more reliable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

On possible way to do it would use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = window.localStorage.getItem('totalSeconds') || 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  window.localStorage.setItem('totalSeconds', totalSeconds);
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something minimal you could use :

```
let timer = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('timer'), 10) || 0
// get what's in the localstorage or start from 0
 const time = document.getElementById('time')
 const setTime = () => {
    timer += 1
    localStorage.setItem('timer', timer)
    time.innerHTML = `time lapsed: ${timer}`
 }

setInterval(setTime, 1000)
```